# Converting JavaScript code to Python

Tags: javascript, python

This is the java script code  it's a decoder with 2 functions:
`getOffset`, and the main function `asdf`.

I want to decode this string: `LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQMJCSVcCgnQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYAUoVMTAdAT33nvX3nB`

To this :

`/ShowUrl-a_partnerKey.1-a_url.http%253A__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F____5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__www__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__danielnyc__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__com__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__-a_urlKey.915edf949f66c826c.html`

I want to convert this (working) javascript code to python:

```
var d = "LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQMJCSVcCgnQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYAUoVMTAdAT33nvX3nB"
function asdf(d) {
var h = {
    "": ["&", "=", "p", "6", "?", "H", "%", "B", ".com", "k", "9", ".html", "n", "M", "r", "www.", "h", "b", "t", "a", "0", "/", "d", "O", "j", "http://", "_", "L", "i", "f", "1", "e", "-", "2", ".", "N", "m", "A", "l", "4", "R", "C", "y", "S", "o", "+", "7", "I", "3", "c", "5", "u", 0, "T", "v", "s", "w", "8", "P", 0, "g", 0],
    q: [0, "__3F__", 0, "Photos", 0, "https://", ".edu", "*", "Y", ">", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "`", "__2D__", "X", "<", "slot", 0, "ShowUrl", "Owners", 0, "[", "q", 0, "MemberProfile", 0, "ShowUserReviews", '"', "Hotel", 0, 0, "Expedia", "Vacation", "Discount", 0, "UserReview", "Thumbnail", 0, "__2F__", "Inspiration", "V", "Map", ":", "@", 0, "F", "help", 0, 0, "Rental", 0, "Picture", 0, 0, 0, "hotels", 0, "ftp://"],
    x: [0, 0, "J", 0, 0, "Z", 0, 0, 0, ";", 0, "Text", 0, "(", "x", "GenericAds", "U", 0, "careers", 0, 0, 0, "D", 0, "members", "Search", 0, 0, 0, "Post", 0, 0, 0, "Q", 0, "$", 0, "K", 0, "W", 0, "Reviews", 0, ",", "__2E__", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "{", "}", 0, "Cheap", ")", 0, 0, 0, "#", ".org"],
    z: [0, "Hotels", 0, 0, "Icon", 0, 0, 0, 0, ".net", 0, 0, "z", 0, 0, "pages", 0, "geo", 0, 0, 0, "cnt", "~", 0, 0, "]", "|", 0, "tripadvisor", "Images", "BookingBuddy", 0, "Commerce", 0, 0, "partnerKey", 0, "area", 0, "Deals", "from", "//", 0, "urlKey", 0, "'", 0, "WeatherUnderground", 0, "MemberSign", "Maps", 0, "matchID", "Packages", "E", "Amenities", "Travel", ".htm", 0, "!", "^", "G"]
};
var b = "";
for (var a = 0; a < d.length; a++) {
    var j = d.charAt(a);
    var f = j;
    if (h[j] && a + 1 < d.length) {
        a++;
        f += d.charAt(a)
    } else {
        j = ""
    }
    var g = getOffset(d.charCodeAt(a));
    if (g < 0 || typeof h[j][g] == "String") {
        b += f
    } else {
        b += h[j][g]
    }
}
return b}
function getOffset(a) {
if (a >= 97 && a <= 122) {
    return a - 61
}
if (a >= 65 && a <= 90) {
    return a - 55
}
if (a >= 48 && a <= 71) {
    return a - 48
}
return -1}
asdf(d)
```

It returns (as expected):

`/ShowUrl-a_partnerKey.1-a_url.http%253A__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F____5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__www__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__danielnyc__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__com__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__-a_urlKey.915edf949f66c826c.html`

This is the Python code that I've tried :

```
d = "LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQMJCSVcCgnQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYAUoVMTAdAT33nvX3nB"

def asdf(d):

 h = {
 "" : ["&", "=", "p", "6", "?", "H", "%", "B", ".com", "k", "9", ".html", "n", "M", "r", "www.", "h", "b", "t", "a", "0", "/", "d", "O", "j", "http://", "_", "L", "i", "f", "1", "e", "-", "2", ".", "N", "m", "A", "l", "4", "R", "C", "y", "S", "o", "+", "7", "I", "3", "c", "5", "u", 0, "T", "v", "s", "w", "8", "P", 0, "g", 0],
 "q": [0, "__3F__", 0, "Photos", 0, "https://", ".edu", "*", "Y", ">", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "`", "__2D__", "X", "<", "slot", 0, "ShowUrl", "Owners", 0, "[", "q", 0, "MemberProfile", 0, "ShowUserReviews", '"', "Hotel", 0, 0, "Expedia", "Vacation", "Discount", 0, "UserReview", "Thumbnail", 0, "__2F__", "Inspiration", "V", "Map", ":", "@", 0, "F", "help", 0, 0, "Rental", 0, "Picture", 0, 0, 0, "hotels", 0, "ftp://"],
 "x": [0, 0, "J", 0, 0, "Z", 0, 0, 0, ";", 0, "Text", 0, "(", "x", "GenericAds", "U", 0, "careers", 0, 0, 0, "D", 0, "members", "Search", 0, 0, 0, "Post", 0, 0, 0, "Q", 0, "$", 0, "K", 0, "W", 0, "Reviews", 0, ",", "__2E__", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "{", "}", 0, "Cheap", ")", 0, 0, 0, "#", ".org"],
 "z": [0, "Hotels", 0, 0, "Icon", 0, 0, 0, 0, ".net", 0, 0, "z", 0, 0, "pages", 0, "geo", 0, 0, 0, "cnt", "~", 0, 0, "]", "|", 0, "tripadvisor", "Images", "BookingBuddy", 0, "Commerce", 0, 0, "partnerKey", 0, "area", 0, "Deals", "from", "//", 0, "urlKey", 0, "'", 0, "WeatherUnderground", 0, "MemberSign", "Maps", 0, "matchID", "Packages", "E", "Amenities", "Travel", ".htm", 0, "!", "^", "G"]
 }
 b = ""

 for a in range(len(d)):
     j=d[a]
     f=j
     list =[]
     for key in h:
        list.append(key)
     if j in list and a+1 < len(d):
         a=a+1
         f = f+d[a]
     else:
         j = ""
     g = getOffset(ord(d[a]))
     if g < 0 or type(h[j][g]) is str:
         b = b + f
     else:
         b = b+str(h[j][g])
         print b
 return b

def getOffset(a):
    if(a >= 97 and a <= 122):
        return(a-61)        
    if(a >= 65 and a <= 90):
        return(a-55)
    if(a >= 48 and a <=71):
        return(a-48)
    return(-1)
print asdf(d)
```

But it gives me back the undecoded string:  `LqMWJQzZYUWJQpEcYGII26XombQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQuuuQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQMJCSVcCgnQQoqnQQQQoqnxioqnQQQQoqnQQniaQQoqnQQQQoqnqgoqnQQQQoqnQQWJQzhYAUoVMTAdAT33nvX3nB`

What's wrong with my code ? Why don't I get the same results as the javascript code ?

Comment: Actually, your Javascript code has an Eo=rror - if the error is fixed, then your JS code breaks, returning the original string, just as your Python code does.  
`typeof h[j][g] == "String")`  should be `if (g < 0 || typeof h[j][g] == "string")` (note uncapitalized **string**)

Comment: Second, your Python code still will not quite yield the result you are expecting because when using `for a in ..` construct, the value of the looping variable will reset itself to the "next" value (ignoring any changes you made within the block), giving you troublesome results. Use `for .. in ..`  in the same way you would use a JavaScript `forEach` Don't change the value of the looping variable, code with the expectation that every element in the iterable will be acted upon (use `break`), or If you want to manually control the value of your looping variable in Python, use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your Javascript code has an Error - if the error is fixed, then your JS code breaks, returning the original string, just as your Python code does.

`if (g < 0 || typeof h[j][g] == "String")` is NOT behaving as you expected:

`typeof h[j][g] == "String")`  should be
`if (g < 0 || typeof h[j][g] == "string")`
(note uncapitalized **string**).

In fact the mistaken `typeof h[j][g] == "String")`, is actually the equivalent of
`if (g < 0) {...`

If you change that line in both versions of your code, you get the desired results in JS, and ALMOST the desired results in Python (which has another error).

---

**Javascript version**

Change  :

```
var g = getOffset(d.charCodeAt(a));
    if (g < 0 || typeof h[j][g] == "String") {     #THIS LINE IS INCORRECT
        b += f
    } else {
        b += h[j][g]
    }
```

To:

```
var g = getOffset(d.charCodeAt(a));
    if (g < 0){                       # CHANGE THIS LINE
        b += f
    } else {
        b += h[j][g]
    }
```

JS Result:

`/ShowUrl-a_partnerKey.1-a_url.http%253A__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F____5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__www__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__danielnyc__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__com__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__-a_urlKey.915edf949f66c826c.html`

---

**Python version**

Change:

```
 g = getOffset(ord(d[a]))
 if g < 0 or type(h[j][g]) is str:    # THIS LINE IS INCORRECT
     b = b + f
 else:
     b = b+str(h[j][g])
     print b                          # THIS LINE SHOULD BE REMOVED
```

To:

```
 g = getOffset(ord(d[a]))             # CHANGED THIS LINE
 if g < 0:
     b = b + f
 else:
     b = b+str(h[j][g])   
     #print b                         # REMOVED THIS LINE
```

Results in:

`/ShowUrld-a_partnerKeyN.1-a_url.http%253A__5Fc____5Fc__2F__y5Fc____5Fc____5Fc____5Fc__2F__y5Fc____5Fc__www__5Fc____5Fc__2E__o5Fc____5Fc__danielnyc__5Fc____5Fc__2E__o5Fc____5Fc__com__5Fc____5Fc__2F__y5Fc____5Fc__-a_urlKeyS.915edf949f66c826c.html`

Here are links to final code in:

- [JavaScript repl](https://repl.it/@sherylhohman/StrictCumbersomeFoxterrier)
- [Python repl](https://repl.it/@sherylhohman/QuietSubtleNortherncardinals)

---

**Final PYTHON Fix**

Now, You have another Python Error..
When using `for a in ..` construct, you cannot internally change the value of `a`, as in the line: `a = a + 1`.

Well, you *can*, but that will lead to unexpected results.
Each time the `for a in..` top of the loop is reached, `a` will increment to the next value it *would have had*, regardless of what value you *temporarily* changed it to *within* the loop !!

Hence, `(2, 'M'), (7, 'Z'), ...` were not skipped, and you had intended!
This is why the Python result I showed above has a few more characters than you expected.

See [these SO answers for great explanations and examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop), and [python docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), or [this closed SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902835/changing-iteration-variable-inside-for-loop-in-python).

The easiest way to convert your code in this case is to simply use a `while` loop instead of a `for in` loop.  This way, the your inner logic remains essentially the same for both languages.

CHANGE:

```
 #for a in range(len(d)):     ## Remove and Change this to a WHILE loop as below
  a = 0                       #  Manually initialize your loop
  print(len(d))
  while a < len(d):           # Use WHILE loop instead 
    j = d[a]

    ...
```

AND..

```
    ...

    g = getOffset(ord(d[a]))
    if  g < 0 :                   # Remember to UPDATE This Line (Remove #or type(h[j][g]) is str:)
        b = b + f
    else:
        b = b + str(h[j][g])
        #print b                  # REMOVE this line

    a = a + 1                     # Manually increment your WHILE loop
  return b
```

[FINAL PYTHON CODE on REPL.IT](https://repl.it/@sherylhohman/QuietSubtleNortherncardinals)
)

FINAL PYTHON RESULT:

`/ShowUrl-a_partnerKey.1-a_url.http%253A__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F____5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__www__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__danielnyc__5F____5F__2E__5F____5F__com__5F____5F__2F__5F____5F__-a_urlKey.915edf949f66c826c.html`