# Trouble scraping a website link using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch a website link connected to this `L'atelier de willy` restaurant from a webpage but I can't make it.

[Website address](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g188644-d14788983-Reviews-Mozart_More_Than_Just_Ribs-Brussels.html)

This is how it is visible in that page (within the same block where the name of the restaurant is visible as very bold letters):

[image]

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g188644-d14788983-Reviews-Mozart_More_Than_Just_Ribs-Brussels.html"

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
website = soup.select_one("[class*='website']").get("data-ahref")
print(website)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
q5aizCJEIWEVtIiYHVLaizCJEIWHEpttVcL4pIaQtipEnV1zS0pIaQaVMSpa1EVTVEEJc
```

What I wish to get:

```
https://mozart-resto.be/
```

***How can I pasre that website link using requests?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The site is using "asdf"-encoder (I'm not sure if that's official name). But using the reply from [Converting JavaScript code to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227463/converting-javascript-code-to-python), you should be able to decode this string:

```
d = "q5aizCJEIWEVtIiYHVLaizCJEIWHEpttVcL4pIaQtipEnV1zS0pIaQaVMSpa1EVTVEEJc"

def asdf(d):

  b = ""
  h = {
    "": ["&", "=", "p", "6", "?", "H", "%", "B", ".com", "k", "9", ".html", "n", "M", "r", "www.", "h", "b", "t", "a", "0", "/", "d", "O", "j", "http://", "_", "L", "i", "f", "1", "e", "-", "2", ".", "N", "m", "A", "l", "4", "R", "C", "y", "S", "o", "+", "7", "I", "3", "c", "5", "u", 0, "T", "v", "s", "w", "8", "P", 0, "g", 0],
    "q": [0, "__3F__", 0, "Photos", 0, "https://", ".edu", "*", "Y", ">", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "`", "__2D__", "X", "<", "slot", 0, "ShowUrl", "Owners", 0, "[", "q", 0, "MemberProfile", 0, "ShowUserReviews", '"', "Hotel", 0, 0, "Expedia", "Vacation", "Discount", 0, "UserReview", "Thumbnail", 0, "__2F__", "Inspiration", "V", "Map", ":", "@", 0, "F", "help", 0, 0, "Rental", 0, "Picture", 0, 0, 0, "hotels", 0, "ftp://"],
    "x": [0, 0, "J", 0, 0, "Z", 0, 0, 0, ";", 0, "Text", 0, "(", "x", "GenericAds", "U", 0, "careers", 0, 0, 0, "D", 0, "members", "Search", 0, 0, 0, "Post", 0, 0, 0, "Q", 0, "$", 0, "K", 0, "W", 0, "Reviews", 0, ",", "__2E__", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "{", "}", 0, "Cheap", ")", 0, 0, 0, "#", ".org"],
    "z": [0, "Hotels", 0, 0, "Icon", 0, 0, 0, 0, ".net", 0, 0, "z", 0, 0, "pages", 0, "geo", 0, 0, 0, "cnt", "~", 0, 0, "]", "|", 0, "tripadvisor", "Images", "BookingBuddy", 0, "Commerce", 0, 0, "partnerKey", 0, "area", 0, "Deals", "from", "//", 0, "urlKey", 0, "'", 0, "WeatherUnderground", 0, "MemberSign", "Maps", 0, "matchID", "Packages", "E", "Amenities", "Travel", ".htm", 0, "!", "^", "G"]
  }

  #for a in range(len(d)):     ## REMOVE and Change this to a WHILE loop (see below)
  a = 0                        #  Manually initialize your loop
  while a < len(d):
    j = d[a]
    f = j
    list = []

    for key in h:
      list.append(key)

    if (j in list) and (a < len(d)):
       a = a + 1                  ## CANNOT DO THIS, if you a use "for a in.." loop.  So, we'll use a WHILE loop instead
       f = f + d[a]
    else:
       j = ""

    g = getOffset(ord(d[a]))
    if  g < 0 :                   ## REMEMBER TO UPDATE THIS LINE to REMOVE # or type(h[j][g]) is str:
        b = b + f
    else:
        b = b + str(h[j][g])
        #print b                  # REMOVE this line

    a = a + 1                     # Manually increment your WHILE loop
  return b

def getOffset(a):
    if(a >= 97 and a <= 122):
        return(a-61)
    if(a >= 65 and a <= 90):
        return(a-55)
    if(a >= 48 and a <=71):
        return(a-48)
    print ("\n\nERROR\n\n")
    return(-1)

print(asdf(d))
```

Prints:

```
https://mozart-resto.be/mozart-brussel/?utm_source=tripadvisor&utm_medium=referral
```

EDIT (For selecting the link):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g188644-d14788983-Reviews-Mozart_More_Than_Just_Ribs-Brussels.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

s = soup.select_one('div[data-ahref]:has(span:contains("Site Web"))')
if s:
    site_web = asdf(s['data-ahref']) # this is the decoder function
    print(site_web)
```

Prints:

```
https://mozart-resto.be/mozart-brussel/?utm_source=tripadvisor&utm_medium=referral
```

Comment: Awesome @Andrej!! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Unfortunately, I don't have commenting yet, and this is supposed to be a comment :(</s>

---

So, your code is looking for `data_ahref` which is supposed to get what your output shows.
The source of the website shows

```html
<div class="is-hidden-mobile blEntry website  ui_link" data-ahref="q5aizCJEIWEVtIiYHVLaizCJEIWHEpttVcL4pIaQtipEnV1zS0pIaQaVMSpa1EVTVEEJc" data-column="2" data-trackingkey="URL_EATERY" data-eventname="bl_contact_website" data-blcontact="URL_HOTEL" onclick="widgetEvCall('handlers.onWebLinkClicked', event, this)"><span class="primary_icon ui_icon laptop"></span><span class="detail ">Site Web</span></div>
```

and it says that `data-ahref="q5aizCJEIWEVtIiYHVLaizCJEIWHEpttVcL4pIaQtipEnV1zS0pIaQaVMSpa1EVTVEEJc"`. This means that your code is working properly (and bs4).

Another thing is that when I click on the `Site Web` link, I am brought to [this link](https://mozart-resto.be/mozart-brussel/?utm_source=tripadvisor&utm_medium=referral) and not the link you wish for. And the link you want is not found anywhere in the source code.

---

So, are you sure you are looking for the right things?

**EDIT:**
Looking at Andrej Kesely's answer, I realize that the first part of my answer doesn't count. I didn't realize that `data-ahref` is actually a encoded string that is the url.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you checkout https://html.python-requests.org/ this was written with the intention of using it for parsing web pages.