# Python changes value of i in for loop does not reflect on loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

My code:

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
    print (i)
    i=i-1;
```

---

### output

0
2
4
6
8

### Press any key to continue . . .

If we decreases value of for i then it is not reflected on for loop why..?

Comment: Because immediately after you change it, it is assigned the next value from range(0, 10, 2).

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15902835/2301450