# How do I accumulate the index for what is for-loops w

Tags: python, for-loop

```
condition = True
for index in range(35, 100):
    if condition == True:
        index += 5
    print(index)
```

The for-loops gives me the result of 40 41 ...... 101 102 103 104 105

I hope that index can be like 35 40 45 50 55.......100

but it's seems like doesn't work properly.

Comment: looks like you need `range(35, 100, 5)` --> `step`

Comment: Thanks for your advise but what if I need to consider the condition while it's True?

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in range(35, 100)
```

This is similar to : `for (int index = 35; index < 100; i++)`
So after each itertion you will have `index += 1`

To solve your problem, you will have to add steps to your range: `range(35, 100, 5)`

```
for index in range(35, 100, 5):
    print(index)
```

-- EDITED

or you can also (as mentionned in the comment):

```
condition = True
for index in range(35, 100):
    if condition == True:
        index += 4
    print(index)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise but what if I need to consider the condition while it's True?

Comment: Then better use while loop. or 

`condition = True
for index in range(35, 100):
    if condition == True:
        index += 4
    print(index)`

Answer (score 0):

use a `while` loop instead

```py
condition = True
index = 35
while index < 100:
    if condition == True:
        index += 5
    else:
        index += 1
    print(index)
```

This way depending on the condition you will add `5` or `1`. We need a `while` loop because we don't exactly know how many time we will go through the loop, so a `for` isn't what you need.
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902835/changing-iteration-variable-inside-for-loop-in-python) you can't add numbers to the iterator in a `for i in range()` loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there, you just need to specify the condition in the loop like this. Your "for loop" will also produce the same result.

```
condition = True
for index in range(35, 100, 5):
    if condition == True: 
        index += 5
    print(index)
```