write a program to print first x terms of the series 3N + 2 which are not multiples of 4 in python
I want to write a program for printing first x terms of series 3n+2 which are not multiple of 4 in python. For this I have written a code using while loop and it is working fine. then I have again wrote the same code using for loop but it is not giving correct answer.
x = int(input())
n = 1
count = 1
while count < x:
    temp = 3*n + 2
    if temp % 4 != 0:
        print(temp, end=" ")
        count += 1
    n += 1

for count in range(x+1):
    temp = 3*n + 2
    if temp % 4 != 0:
        print(temp, end=" ")
    else:
        count -= 1
    n += 1

above is the code both in while loop and for loop but for loop code is giving wrong answer(basically not all terms are getting printed for higher number like x=5 or above).
I am expecting to get the same output for 2nd code (for loop) as I am getting in 1st code(while loop)

In the for loop, else: count -= 1 is superfluous since count will be overwritten on the next iteration by the next value returned by range. This has the side effect of printing less than x terms.

@001 thanks..this give me the idea where to look for correction in code. writing here the updated version which is working                                                                   for i in range(x):     temp = 3*n + 2     while temp % 4 == 0:         n += 1         temp = 3*n + 2     print(temp,end=" ")     n += 1

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902835/changing-iteration-variable-inside-for-loop-in-python/15903677#15903677

The issue in your second code (using a for loop) is that you're resetting count to 0 in the else block when temp % 4 == 0. This is causing the loop to skip counting some terms.
x = int(input())
count = 0
for n in range(1, x+1):
    temp = 3*n + 2
    if temp % 4 != 0:
        print(temp, end=" ")
        count += 1
    if count == x:
        break

I think I understand it, but I may not understand it. Can you try it?
